# Display Posts from Category Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, function, shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode in Wordpress to display a list of posts from a certain category (ID=1361...our podcasts category). When I use the code below, it only displays the shortcode text ([pages_posts]), not the list of posts. Any ideas?

```
// Podcast Page Listing shortcode
function podcast_pages_posts() {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'cat'=> 1361,
);

$podcast_pages_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $podcast_pages_posts->have_posts() ):
    $ppp_output = '<ul>';
    while ( $podcast_pages_posts->have_posts() ) : $podcast_pages_posts->the_post();
        $ppp_output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endwhile; 
    $ppp_output .= '</ul>';
endif;

return $ppp_output;
wp_reset_postdata();

}
add_shortcode( 'pages_posts', 'podcast_pages_posts' );
```

Here is a page where it is not working: http://www.churchmarketingsucks.com/developer-test/
Here is a page on the same site where another shortcode is working (it's the list at the bottom), so I don't think the site is rejecting shortcodes altogether: http://www.churchmarketingsucks.com/cmp/

Comment: just to be clear, this code is in the `functions.php` file of your current active theme?

Comment: also, you cant have anything after a `return` statement

Comment: @celeriko is right, you should run `wp_reset_postdata();` before the return (kudos though most people use wp_reset_query() which is inefficient). Can you verify that THIS shortcode is working by maybe returning a static string, the code looks fine.

Comment: @celeriko - that was the key! I, like an idiot, was working in functions.php in my MOBILE theme instead of my main theme. #fail

I also moved the wp_reset_query() above the return as suggested.

All is working properly now! Thanks guys! How can I properly mark this as answered? Do I mark the original post?

Comment: @user2805240 happens to the best of us, glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

I've been tinkering with this same issue and have found this solution to work. Place in the functions.php file. Then place shortcode in your page like [homepage_info id="234"]

```
// shortcode for specific category.  Use on homepage (or wherever) to display a list of categories of posts
function quick_info_shorty( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 17      // Add the *default category id
    ), $atts ) );

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'cat'       => $id,
    ) );

    $return = '';
    $return .= '<div class="homepage_info_box">';

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $return .= '<a class="item" href="' . $permalink . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title ) . '</a>';
    } 

$return .= '</div>';
return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'homepage_info', 'quick_info_shorty' );  
// place in page: [homepage_info]   Simple & clean for clients
// OR
// [homepage_info id="x"]           (x = id of category/categories other than *default category id.
```